# Adding floating action menu in webview?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-webview

I totally screwed but there is something error with my XML as it crashes, I don't know how to make it work, i want to place floating action menu on down right corner in webview but failed to do so, any suggestion from expert.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/material_design_android_floating_action_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
        fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="55"
        fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
        fab:menu_colorNormal="#da3c2f"
        fab:menu_colorPressed="#dc4b3f"
        fab:menu_colorRipple="#99d4d4d4"
        fab:menu_fab_label="Floating Action Menu"
        fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
        fab:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
        fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333"
        fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444"
        fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66efecec"
        fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
        fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
        fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
        fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
        fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
        fab:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_position="left"
        fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
        fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
        fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
        fab:menu_labels_textColor="#f2f1f1"
        fab:menu_labels_textSize="15sp"
        fab:menu_openDirection="up"
        fab:menu_shadowColor="#66aff198"
        fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
        fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
        fab:menu_shadowYOffset="4dp"
        fab:menu_showShadow="true">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/material_design_floating_action_menu_item1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_find"
            fab:fab_label="Menu Item 1"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/material_design_floating_action_menu_item2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_find"
            fab:fab_label="Menu Item 2"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/material_design_floating_action_menu_item3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_find"
            fab:fab_label="Menu Item 3"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

        <WebView android:id="@+id/myWebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
  
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>





</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use `RelativeLayout` as your rootView.

Comment: Yup i changed before it self doesn't work once again crash Mr.SripadRaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    </WebView>

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        android:id="@+id/right_labels"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/white"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
        fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/half_black"
        fab:fab_addButtonSize="mini"
        fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
        fab:fab_labelsPosition="left">

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
            fab:fab_title="Label on the right"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_title="Another one on the right"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>

    </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>v

</RelativeLayout>
```

used this library
https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button

Hope this helps.

Comment: Mr.Nikhil Borad thanks for your valuable replay, helped me out.

Comment: How to add the   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView> it doesn't fit over laps any suggestion which turned to be against the google admob policy

Comment: mean to say you want to put in bottom of screen...?

Answer (score 1):

You can use framelayout.

[image]

Like :

```
<FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:padding="20dp"
       android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark">
      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:padding="20dp"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:background="@android:color/holo_purple">

          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:padding="20dp"
              android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">

          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>
      </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
  </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Ahmad for picture and explanation, helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

Balaji JB try to this code hope this can help you..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/myWebView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="end">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/material_design_android_floating_action_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
        fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="55"
        fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
        fab:menu_colorNormal="#da3c2f"
        fab:menu_colorPressed="#dc4b3f"
        fab:menu_colorRipple="#99d4d4d4"
        fab:menu_fab_label="Floating Action Menu"
        fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
        fab:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
        fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333"
        fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444"
        fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66efecec"
        fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
        fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
        fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
        fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
        fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
        fab:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_position="left"
        fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
        fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
        fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
        fab:menu_labels_textColor="#f2f1f1"
        fab:menu_labels_textSize="15sp"
        fab:menu_openDirection="up"
        fab:menu_shadowColor="#66aff198"
        fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
        fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
        fab:menu_shadowYOffset="4dp"
        fab:menu_showShadow="true">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/material_design_floating_action_menu_item1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_find"
            fab:fab_label="Menu Item 1"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/material_design_floating_action_menu_item2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_find"
            fab:fab_label="Menu Item 2"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/material_design_floating_action_menu_item3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_find"
            fab:fab_label="Menu Item 3"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />
    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" /></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Mr.Dileep Patel thanks for your valuable replay, helped me out.

Comment: Hi Balaji JB if this can help you then accpet my answer and upvote this..thanks